# Set the active material output node with python

Tags: python, materials

Output nodes have a `is_active_output` property, but it doesn't seem possible to set this consistently.

I believe there's a bug where doing `node.is_active_output = True` does nothing unless you first click in the UI on one of the output nodes to change which one is active, then after that `node.is_active_output = True` will work.

However I need to stick to the current latest Blender version and cannot wait for [this to be patched](https://developer.blender.org/T96292). Is there some other way to consistently set what the active material output node is? Preferably without deleting any nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [this patch](https://developer.blender.org/rB40cbbe809c0afe83068cdca97992204d7b135b9e) the bug is solved. You'll either have to download the latest 3.2 alpha build or wait for the official release which will be in 3 or 4 months from now if I'm not mistaken.

Here's a snippet to toggle between 2 outputs in the world shader (inspired by developer Jacques Lucke in the bug report):

```
import bpy

n1 = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes['World Output']
n2 = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes['World Output.001']

if not n1.is_active_output:
    n1.is_active_output = True
else:
    n2.is_active_output = True
```

[image: ![image|490x291](upload://bEMEzMZdHkuWbWSsH0FHI0uW5Eq.png)]

Comment: Yeah as I understand it, now (as before) just setting `is_active_output = True` on any node will automatically set other output nodes to `False` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this, it also works for material outputs, but somehow nobody talks about that...